# API key from Thunderforest for OpenLayers does not work

Tags: openlayers, api

I’m using OpenLayers v6.14.1 and I’m trying to put to work my API key from [www.thunderforest.com](http://www.thunderforest.com), according to guidance at https://www.thunderforest.com/tutorials/openlayers/ but it does not work. The weird thing is the following code gives me the open street standard map, instead the map I want (spinal-map), the same happened if I ask for any other map available for my API key. How can I do this?

```
const openStreetMapStandard………

const ThunderforestTransport = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM("OpenCycleMap", ['https://tile.thunderforest.com/spinal-map/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'] ), visible: true, title: 'ThunderforestTransport' })

//layer group

const baseLayerGroup = new ol.layer.Group({
    layers: [
        openStreetMapStandard, ThunderforestTransport]
     })
map.addLayer(baseLayerGroup);
```

Comment: The API key does work.  You cannot use code from an OpenLayers 2 example in OpenLayers 6, You must use OpenLayers 6 sysntax `const ThunderforestTransport = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM({url: 'https://tile.thunderforest.com/spinal-map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'})  })`

Comment: Thanks a lot, problem solved.